# LPTHW Ex 52 Bug Python 2.7 web.py frame work

Tags: python, forms, python-2.7, web.py

Hi I am working on the final exercise of Learn Python the hard way online found at:
https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/ex52.html

In the app.py code he tells us there is a bug :

```html
import web
from gothonweb import map

urls = (
  '/game', 'GameEngine',
  '/', 'Index',
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

# little hack so that debug mode works with sessions
if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    store = web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
    session = web.session.Session(app, store,
                                  initializer={'room': None})
    web.config._session = session
else:
    session = web.config._session

render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")


class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        # this is used to "setup" the session with starting values
        session.room = map.START
        web.seeother("/game")

class GameEngine(object):

    def GET(self):
        if session.room:
            return render.show_room(room=session.room)
        else:
            # why is there here? do you need it?
            #this is to render death screen
            # this is the none part of the get in the 'go' method
            return render.you_died()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(action=None)

        # there is a bug here, can you fix it?
        if session.room and form.action:
            session.room = session.room.go(form.action)

        web.seeother("/game")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

So my issue is where it says there is a bug in the POST def. From testing it out it all seems to be working. I can't see where the bug really is in this part of the code. Any sort of help with the direction i should go will really be appreciated!

Comment: This is not a support service for LPTHW.

Comment: Apologies! I was just hoping to get some insight on how it could be a big to improve my own code.